# How to implement login authentication to my Vue NodeJS restful API?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, restful-authentication

I am new to Stackoverflow so please forgive me if my question is bit difficult to understand. However, background of my problem is following.

I have created a NodeJS RESTful API based on the following tutorial -
https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

I have also created a Vue based frontend what I use to display data from database with GET request, POST new data to database and also PATCH/DELETE requests.

I need to create a login/registration system to secure my api endpoints so that the unauthorized person cannot see/delete/modify the content but I have no idea where to start or how to implement it.

My project frontend and backend repositories are visible on:

Frontend - https://github.com/umbluu/mufc-api-fe
Backend - https://github.com/umbluu/mufc-api-be

Can someone please point out some hints/tips how to proceed with my task?

Comment: You probably want to read up on JWT - JSON Web Tokens. Check https://jwt.io/ for starters and then maybe something like https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-mini-invoicing-application-with-vue-and-nodejs-jwt-authentication-and-sending-invoices

Comment: Hi Andre and welcome to Stack Overflow!  As is, this question is too broad for the SO guidelines.  Could you maybe make it more specific, for instance by focusing the question on a particular aspect of the system?  Note also that questions asking for library or resource recommendations or comparisons between similar technologies are generally not allowed and certainly discouraged.  So this question might make more sense on another forum such as Reddit ...